# Splitting a string based on a certain set of words?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out how to take a phrase and split it up into a list of separate strings based on the occurrence of certain words.

Examples are probably be the easiest way to explain what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
List splitters = ['ABOVE', 'AT', 'NEAR', 'IN'];

INPUT: "ALFALFA DITCH IN ECKERT CO";
OUTPUT: ["ALFALFA DITCH", "IN ECKERT CO"];

INPUT: 'ANIMAS RIVER AT DURANGO, CO';
OUTPUT: ['ANIMAS RIVER', 'AT DURANGO, CO'];

INPUT: 'ALAMOSA RIVER ABOVE WILSON CREEK IN JASPER, CO';
OUTPUT ['ALAMOSA RIVER', 'ABOVE WILSON CREEK IN JASPER, CO'];
```

Notice in the third example, when there are multiple occurrences of splitters in the input phrase, I only want to use the first one.

To my knowledge, the split() method doesn't support multiple strings I can't find a single example of this in dart. I would think there is a simple solution?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a `RegExp` then

```dart
var splitters = ['ABOVE', 'AT', 'NEAR', 'IN'];
var s = "ALFALFA DITCH IN ECKERT CO";
var splitterRE = RegExp(splitters.join('|'));

var match = splitterRE.firstMatch(s);
if (match ! null) {
 var partOne = s.substring(0, match.start).trimRight();
 var partTwo = s.substring(match.start);
}
```

That does what you ask for, but it's slightly unsafe.
It will find "IN" in "BEHIND" if given "BEHIND THE FARM IN ALABAMA".
You likely want to match only complete words. In that case, `RegExp`s are even more helpful, since they can do that too. Change the line to:

```dart
  var splitterRE = RegExp(r'\b(?:' + splitters.join('|') + r')\b');
```

then it will only match entire words.